# Fill Grid component with Data from MongoDB records

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, syncfusion

I have data stored in a MongoDB collection. I can get the data with the following

```
const [recruitList, setRecruitList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/read').then((res) => {
    setRecruitList(res.data);
  });
}, []);
```

Now, I have the following Grid Component from @syncfusion/ej2-react-grids

````
import * as React from 'react';
import { Grid, GridModel } from '@syncfusion/ej2-grids';
import { DefaultHtmlAttributes } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-base';
export interface GridTypecast {
    rowTemplate?: string | Function | any;
    detailTemplate?: string | Function | any;
    toolbarTemplate?: string | Function | any;
    pagerTemplate?: string | Function | any;
    editSettingsTemplate?: string | Function | any;
    groupSettingsCaptionTemplate?: string | Function | any;
}
/**
 * `GridComponent` represents the react Grid.
 * ```tsx
 * <GridComponent dataSource={data} allowPaging={true} allowSorting={true}/>
 * ```
 */
export declare class GridComponent extends Grid {
    state: Readonly<{
        children?: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
    }> & Readonly<GridModel & DefaultHtmlAttributes | GridTypecast>;
    setState: any;
    private getDefaultAttributes;
    initRenderCalled: boolean;
    private checkInjectedModules;
    directivekeys: {
        [key: string]: Object;
    };
    private immediateRender;
    props: Readonly<{
        children?: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
    }> & Readonly<GridModel & DefaultHtmlAttributes | GridTypecast>;
    forceUpdate: (callBack?: () => any) => void;
    context: Object;
    portals: any;
    isReactComponent: Object;
    refs: {
        [key: string]: React.ReactInstance;
    };
    constructor(props: any);
    render(): any;
}
````

> Orders.js

Calling GridComponent like so.

```
<GridComponent
  id="gridcomp"
  dataSource={ordersData}
  allowPaging
  allowSorting
  allowExcelExport
  allowPdfExport
  contextMenuItems={contextMenuItems}
  editSettings={editing}
>
  <ColumnsDirective>
    {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */}
    {ordersGrid.map((item, index) => <ColumnDirective key={index} {...item} />)}
  </ColumnsDirective>
  <Inject services={[Resize, Sort, ContextMenu, Filter, Page, ExcelExport, Edit, PdfExport]} />
</GridComponent>
```

This is the dataSource parameter also from the same project @syncfusion/ej2-react-grids

```
    * @default []
    * @isGenericType true
    */
dataSource: Object | DataManager | DataResult;
```

For now, if I do this in

> dummy.js

```
export const ordersData = [
  {
    Degree: 10248,
    RecruitName: 'Vinet',

    RecruitEmail: 32.38,
    PhoneNumber: '51481369',
    Skills: 'USA',
    Status: 'pending',
    StatusBg: '#FB9678',
    ProductImage:
      product6,
  },
];
```

This static data is displayed. And I can keep generating as many rows in the grid as I want statically. But I didn't know how I can pass data from all my collection records there instead.

This is the structure of the grid:

> dummy.js

```
export const ordersGrid = [
  {
    headerText: 'Image',
    template: gridOrderImage,
    textAlign: 'Center',
    width: '120',
  },
  {
    field: 'RecruitName',
    headerText: 'Name',
    width: '150',
    editType: 'dropdownedit',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },
  { field: 'RecruitEmail',
    headerText: 'Email',
    width: '150',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },
  { field: 'PhoneNumber',
    headerText: 'Phone Number',
    width: '150',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },
  {
    headerText: 'Status',
    template: gridOrderStatus,
    field: 'OrderItems',
    textAlign: 'Center',
    width: '120',
  },
  {
    field: 'Degree',
    headerText: 'Degree',
    width: '120',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },

  {
    field: 'Skills',
    headerText: 'Skills',
    width: '150',
    textAlign: 'Center',
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, you want to add the data which you have got from the MangoDB in your react grid. We suggest you to use the dataSource property of the EJ2 Grid to set the data to the grid.

Please refer the below code example.

```
<GridComponent
  id="gridcomp"
  dataSource={ recruitList}
  allowPaging
  allowSorting
  allowExcelExport
  allowPdfExport
  contextMenuItems={contextMenuItems}
  editSettings={editing}
>
  <ColumnsDirective>
    {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */}
    {ordersGrid.map((item, index) => <ColumnDirective key={index} {...item} />)}
  </ColumnsDirective>
  <Inject services={[Resize, Sort, ContextMenu, Filter, Page, ExcelExport, Edit, PdfExport]} />
</GridComponent>
```